# Positioning else condition in php

Tags: php, if-statement

I have found this little piece of php codes that suites my requirements.

```
<?php
$allDocs = mysql_query("SELECT id, parent FROM modx_site_content ORDER BY id DESC");
while($doc = mysql_fetch_assoc($allDocs)) {
$parent = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM modx_site_content WHERE parent = " . $doc['id'] . " AND id = " . $doc['parent']);
if(mysql_num_rows($parent)) {
while($parentDoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($parent)) {
echo 'Infinte loop found<br /><br />';
echo 'Document #' . $doc['id'] . ' and document #' . $parentDoc['id'] . ' are each others parent.'; 
}
}       
}
?>
```

I tried putting the else condition like this:

```
<?php
$allDocs = mysql_query("SELECT id, parent FROM modx_site_content ORDER BY id DESC");
while($doc = mysql_fetch_assoc($allDocs)) {
$parent = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM modx_site_content WHERE parent = " . $doc['id'] . " AND id = " . $doc['parent']);
if(mysql_num_rows($parent)) {
while($parentDoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($parent)) {
echo 'Infinte loop found<br /><br />';
echo 'Document #' . $doc['id'] . ' and document #' . $parentDoc['id'] . ' are each others parent.'; 
}
}
else {
    echo 'No loop found';
}   
}
?>
```

But it goes into the while loop. Where is the appropriate place to put the else condition?

Comment: How is the ELSE condition supposed to stop the flow of the program to enter the second while loop? The conditional there is whether or not you got results from the second query.

Comment: Does it mean I need to endwhile somewhere in between before else?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Print "No loop found" if there are no results? If that's the case, your code is correct, you just need to make sure that this query: "$parent = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM modx_site_content WHERE parent = " . $doc['id'] . " AND id = " . $doc['parent']);" returns no results to try it.

Comment: Yes definitely would like to print "No loop found" if there are no results. As Marco suggested, I inserted 'break;' after the 'else' echo and that prevented the echoed object of 'else' to go in while loop. I am not sure if that also prevents the intended objects to go in 'while' loop.

Answer (score 0):

Indenting was the solution:

```
<?php
$allDocs = mysql_query("SELECT id, parent FROM modx_site_content ORDER BY id DESC");
while($doc = mysql_fetch_assoc($allDocs)) {
    $parent = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM modx_site_content WHERE parent = " . $doc['id'] . " AND id = " . $doc['parent']);
    if(mysql_num_rows($parent)) {
        while($parentDoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($parent)) {
            echo 'Infinte loop found<br /><br />';
            echo 'Document #' . $doc['id'] . ' and document #' . $parentDoc['id'] . ' are each others parent.'; 
        }
    } else {
        //Your Code Here
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

The else of the if is inside the first loop but not the second.

Edit:Added the Break to Exit Loop.

Comment: It still goes in the loop.

Comment: IT'S exactly as you want. The if is inside the loop, then the else is inside the loop.

Comment: Any way I can escape the while loop for else Marco?

Comment: Edited, you can use break; to exit active loops. as php net says -> http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: Adding break; did the job. Thanks Marco.

Answer (score 0):

Please intent your codeexample before submitting your question. Easeier to read...

It seems like the else-statement is placed correct. Look at your while-statements. Maybe the code never reaches the if-else statement because the first while-loop quits before the if-statemnt gets false. Or as long as the first while-loop runs, you'll always get a row with the the statement

```
$parent = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM modx_site_content WHERE parent = " . $doc['id'] . " AND id = " . $doc['parent']);
```